# Automatically convert nested classes to compact style in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have a very large codebase that uses a mix of nested and compact styles for class definitions.

[RuboCop: ClassAndModuleChildren](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/ClassAndModuleChildren)

```
# Nested
class Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

# Compact
class Foo::Bar
end
```

I'm building an automated tool that uses regular expressions to reorganize the namespaces of a large number of classes. This is easy to do when the class definitions are in the compact format, but much more difficult when they are in the nested format.

Therefore, I need a way to transform all instances of the nested style into the compact style.

I was hoping RuboCop could do this for me, and while the [docs](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_style/#styleclassandmodulechildren) seems to suggest it supports autocorrect, I cannot get it to work. RuboCop reports the offenses, but does not fix it.

```
bundle exec rubocop --auto-correct app/controllers/announcements_controller.rb
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

app/controllers/announcements_controller.rb:1:8: C: Style/ClassAndModuleChildren: Use compact module/class definition instead of nested style.
module Vapid
       ^^^^^
app/controllers/announcements_controller.rb:2:10: C: Style/ClassAndModuleChildren: Use compact module/class definition instead of nested style.
  module V2
         ^^

1 file inspected, 2 offenses detected
```

I'd appreciate if someone can make this work, or knows a better way to automatically adopt the compact style.

Comment: Which version of RuboCop are you using?

Comment: @AndyWaite `0.71.0`

Comment: just want to point out that the two styles are not exactly the same thing, the 'compact' style will error if the parent class is not yet defined

Comment: Have you given a try to do this through code, e.g. `ObjectSpace.each_object` traversal?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is **don't do it**. You (and whoever wrote that Cop) are making a bad assumption that the two "styles" actually do the same thing. They don't. The later is regarded as a really bad practice.

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
>   nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
>   constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
>   module nesting at the point of definition.
>   - [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide)

So lets say you have:

```
module Foo
  TEST = "I'm nested in Foo"
end

module Foo
  class Bar
    puts TEST
  end
end
```

This will put `I'm nested in Foo` since `TEST` is resolved to `Foo::TEST`. Lets change the class definition to use the scope resolution operator:

```
TEST = "I'm in the global scope"

module Foo
  TEST = "I'm nested in Foo"
end

class Foo::Bar
  puts TEST
end
```

This will put `I'm in the global scope`. Because the module nesting is still the global scope and `TEST` resolves to `::TEST`. Your little "improvement" will actually break any code that relies on proper module nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue for one of my Rails apps. For a bunch of `Pundit` policies that reside in nested subfolders of `app/policies`, the following worked for me (with Rubocop 1.24.0/Rails 7.0/MRI 3.0.0):

```
# Rails.root/.rubocop.yml
Style/ClassAndModuleChildren:
  EnforcedStyle: compact
```

then from the command line:

```
rubocop --only Style/ClassAndModuleChildren -A app/policies/*
```

This automagically changed

```
class TestSpecimen
  class TapePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  end
end
```

to

```
class TestSpecimen::TapePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
end
```

and made analogous changes to 59 other code occassions.

Answer (score 0):

> The simple answer is don't do it. You (and whoever wrote that Cop) are making a bad assumption that the two "styles" actually do the same thing. They don't. The later is regarded as a really bad practice.

I do not agree with the answer. Of course all written is valid from the ruby evaluation point of view, however I didn't see any real-world projects where you define the same constant on class/module/global level and then use this constant in your instance, this is in general bad approach and anti-pattern. I would say this example is too awkward and rare to care about it, but you should keep it in mind when using `compact` style.

Besides that there's a problem with `nested` style, examine this:

```rb
module MyApp
  module Writer
    module Log
      class Console
        def do_something
          'deeply nested'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You have your favorite editor opened, and you need to copy that class and test this method from your beloved console. How would you do it? You will have to copy each module name one by one and then concatenate them manually in console. Of course you can later use some gem and define short versions of such modules for example gem [`lazy_names`](https://github.com/zhisme/lazy_names). But isn't it too much actions to do for simple console method call? For me too much, I'm lazy.

What is really handsome with `compact` style, that you will have your class written like so.

```rb
class MyApp::Writer::Log::Console
  def do_something
  end
end
```

You can just select the class name via 1 action by your mouse/touchpad and copypaste to your beloved console.

```bash
#=> MyApp::Writer::Log::Console.do_something
```

And that's it easy and fast, will do for lazy people.

---

So I would really advise to use this `Cop` by default everywhere.

```yaml
# your/project/path/.rubocop.yml
# ....
Style/ClassAndModuleChildren:
  EnforcedStyle: compact
# other cops
```